# Given N observations - Bayesian Posterior for Unknown Variance of a Normal Distribution with a Known Mean?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, bayesian, bayes-theorem

So, starting from no information besides N trials from a Gaussian with $\mu = 0$, I'd like to know the best Bayesian posterior for the unknown variance, $\sigma^2$.

My approach so far as been to assume a uniform prior for $\tau = \frac{1}{\sigma}$, i.e. the scaling factor for the standard Gaussian. In addition to being more intuitive **(to me)**, this is also necessary, since attempting to use a uniform prior for $\sigma$ or $\sigma^2$ would result in a divergent integral.

Then for N observations, this results in a posterior distribution of:

$Pr(\tau|x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = \frac{S^{n+1}\tau^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}exp(-\frac{\tau^2}{2}S^2)$

where $S^2 = x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2$, i.e. the sum of squares of observations.

If we transform variables to the variance, then we have:

$Pr(\sigma^2|x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = \frac{(\frac{S^2}{2})^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})(\sigma^2)^{\frac{n+3}{2}}}exp(-\frac{S^2}{2}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}) = InvGamma({\sigma^2;\alpha = \frac{n + 1}{2},\beta = \frac{S^2}{2})}$.

Thankfully, this is none other than the Inverse Gamma Distribution with parameters $\alpha = \frac{n + 1}{2}, \beta = \frac{S^2}{2}$, which comports with this **rather cryptic statement** on this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution:

> "Perhaps the chief use of the inverse gamma distribution is in
> Bayesian statistics, where the distribution arises as the marginal
> posterior distribution for the unknown variance of a normal
> distribution, if an uninformative prior is used"

**So my question:** Well, this is all well and good, but I haven't found anything resembling this analysis anywhere else online, which is worrying. Moreover, the mean of the posterior distribution I derived is $\frac{S^2}{n-1}$, and the mode is $\frac{S^2}{n+3}$. I'd sort of suspect at least one of those would be $\frac{S^2}{n}$ since we **know** the mean, and we therefore don't lose a degree of freedom when estimating the variance....

Help point me in the right direction? I'm confused.